# How do I pass a list of values to xargs as a single argument list?

Tags: bash, xargs

I know I can use `xargs` to get a list of files and run a command once for each one of those files.

What I'd like to do is pass a list of files as single argument list to a command. For example:

`ls | tail -10`

outputs

```
a
b
c
d
```

but I'd like to pipe it to a command the will receive the list like this:

`command a b c d`

I'm guessing `xargs` is the best tool for the job, but I'm open for anything. The simpler to remember the better.

Comment: With `command a b c d`, the list is not a single argument, but four arguments. Probably you forgot to write _list_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
ls|xargs command
```

will do. Of course, if the list doesn't exceed the command line length limit,

```
command `ls`
```

also suffices.

Comment: If the OP really wants the filenames joined as a single argument, this is incorrect.

Comment: If you read the title of his question and the corrected question, you would have seen that this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Just use quotes and variable expansion:

```
command "$(ls | tail)"
```

to test (`command`):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

*Output:*

```
 a b c d
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
command $(ls|tail -10|paste -s)
```

if you want to have space as separator:

```
command $(ls|tail -10|paste -s -d" ")
```

also xargs has a `-n` option, you could give a shot. for example:

```
kent$  seq 5 
1
2
3
4
5

kent$  seq 5|xargs -n5
1 2 3 4 5
```